# Loading incremental data from Dynamo DB to S3 in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, etl, aws-glue

Is there any option to load data incrementally from Amazon DynamoDB to Amazon S3 in AWS Glue. Bookmark option is enabled but It is not working. It is loading complete data. Is bookmark option not applicable for loading from Dynamodb?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Glue doesn't support job bookmarking for DynamoDB source, it only accepts S3 source :/
To load DynamoDB data incrementally you might use DynamoDB Streams to only process new data.

Answer (score 1):

Enable dynamo streams for your table and use lambda to save those streams on s3. This will provide you more control over your data